# Is there a lazy initialization of Unwind Tables for EH in x86 32-bit Linux G++ 3.4 at runtime?

Tags: linux, exception, g++

Is there a **lazy initialization** in the **EH / unwinding** system in G++ 3.4 table driven exceptions ("DWARF" not sjlj)?

- Decompression of tables?
- Load?

The documentation at the GCC site seems to indicate that there is none, but it is not well documented.

**Background:**

Our developers report that there is a *huge* delay between throw and catch of the *first* exception in our program (0.23 sec!). Exceptions thrown later on do not exhibit such a long delay.

This now exceeds the watchdog interval by an order if 10. The excess time seems to have been introduced by a recent increase in code size / unwind table size. (Current Code size is not huge, only about 300.000 LOC).

The project uses G++ 3.4.x on 32-bit x86 Linux platform (no realtime kernel) single threaded. (Other Compiler version is not an option)

The delay has been reported to have been verified with a simple dummy exception:

```
clock_t t;
try {
  t = clock();
  throw 1;
}
catch(...){
  clock_t x = clock() - t;
  std::cout << (x * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC) << std::endl;
}
```

Any other clues, what could cause the exorbitant delay? (No timer synchronization present, so clock should be Ok.)